# Does collecting coins increase your score?

Tags: temple-run-2

Does collecting coins in Temple Run 2 increase your score? It seems like it does slightly, but I can't tell and would like a precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does slightly, just as what you guessed. Apparently, *Temple Run 2's* gameplay is no different to its first game but quality and sequence of events. So, as this [blog](https://templerunscoring.wordpress.com/) says, it is precisely affecting your score in little amounts. And of course as mentioned by @aytimothy don't forget the multiplier! Different enhancements in scores are also written [there](https://templerunscoring.wordpress.com/), so it's worth a read.

> The 3 basic elements that give a score:
>
> - 1 point for each meter you run
> - 5 point for each coin collected
> - 25 points for each power-up collected

Comment: Don't forget the multiplier.

Comment: Ah yes. Of course the multiplier. Let me credit you with that.